# How to change size of VScale in GTK Python

Tags: python, pygtk

I have added a gtk.VScale() to my GUI and the size is really small, but why ?

I have this code sample :

```
def __init__(self, parent, grid):
    self.parent = parent

    self.tooltips = gtk.Tooltips()

    self.ajustement = gtk.Adjustment(0.0, 0.0, 101.0, 0.1, 1.0, 1.0)
    self.scaleH = gtk.VScale(self.ajustement)

    self.bt_lumiere = gtk.ToggleButton()
    self.bt_lumiere.set_active(False)
    self.bt_lumiere.set_image(gtk.image_new_from_file('data/icons/moon.jpg'))
    self.bt_lumiere.connect("pressed",self.on_changer_etat_lumiere)

    self.barreLumiere = BarreLuminosite(self)

    box = gtk.VBox(False,5)
    box.pack_start(self.bt_lumiere, True)
    box.pack_start(self.scaleH,True)

    grid.attach(self.align(box, padright=1, padleft=1), 1,2,1,5)

def align(self, widget, xalign=0, yalign=0.5, padtop=0, padbottom=0, padleft=0, padright=0):
    ali = gtk.Alignment(xalign=xalign, yalign=yalign)
    ali.add(widget)
    ali.set_padding(padtop, padbottom, padleft, padright)
    return ali
```

The result :
[image: result]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the Gtk or the python version, so it's difficult to answer. This code is for Gtk 3, and Python 3, using introspection. Maybe this helps:

```
hbox = Gtk.HBox()
large_label = Gtk.Label("Large label")
self.ajuste = Gtk.Adjustment(0.0, 0.0, 101.0, 0.1, 1.0, 10)
self.vscale = Gtk.VScale.new(self.ajuste)

vbox = Gtk.VBox()
lbl = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name( "system-run", Gtk.IconSize.DND)
vbox.pack_start(lbl, False, False, 0)
vbox.pack_start(self.vscale, True, True, 0)

hbox.pack_start(large_label, False, False, 0)
hbox.pack_start(vbox, False, False, 0)

self.add(hbox)
self.show_all()
```

Note that in `vbox.pack_start` for the `vscale`, the sizing options are `True`, so that the scale can expand.

You can also call `set_size_request` on the scale, and you can change the margins with `set_margin_left`, `set_margin_right`, `_bottom` and `_top`. The result of the above code is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using PyGTK (GTK2) and Python 2.7.
The code doesn't work : http://puu.sh/v8Sat/c112108014.png

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I ran the same program under Python 2.7. I did use the newer Gnome Introspection system (gi.repository). I wonder if you simply do an `import gtk` or if you have `from gi.repository import Gtk`. The latter is the recommended way, and I suspect that the gtk versions for the old 'import' are not as updated (if at all).

Comment: You were right. It's `self.vscale.set_size_request(30, 100)` the right solution. It's working now :) Ty !